# Which ideal gas law does a constant volume thermometer work on?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

I searches online for my question and found mixed answers. I think the Ans. Should be Gay Lussac's Law as we are dealing with a case of constant volume but variable pressure and temperature. In many books the answer is given to be Charles Law. Would appreciate if someone gave me the ans. Thanks.

Comment: How many ideal gas laws are there?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Sorry for not giving the complete info. There are 4 ideal gas laws which i have been taught of. Charles Law, Gay Lussac's Law, Boyel's Law and Avagrados Law

Comment: @user516256 There is *one* ideal gas law.

Comment: @andselisk Arent the laws from which the ideal gas eq. Is derived also called ideal gas laws? Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: No. Those are just *gas laws* from which, as you said, *ideal gas law* is derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gay-Lussac's Pressure Temperature Law.**

The law simply states

> The pressure of a gas of fixed mass and fixed volume, is directly proportional to the gas's absolute temperature.

As telling temperature rises, the gas in the thermometer has its pressure increased in accordance with the law. Measuring this pressure gives us the temperature as per the *ideal gas equation*, or by using Gay-Lussac's law directly, taking the pressure ratio against a set base temperature and pressure.

Comment: So you are suggesting the answer is Gay Lussac's Law? I know how to calculate the temp but i need the principle on which it works in. In most books and even on Wikipedia it says that it works on Charles Law rather than Gay Lussac's Law.

Comment: I think you're reading the wrong part. *Volume thermometers*, which I believe you're reading, work by measuring volume at a constant pressure. What you're asking about is a ***constant** volume gas thermometer*, which measures changes in pressure against a constant volume.

Comment: I didnt know there was a diffrence. I shouldve tried to frame my question better. Can you tell me about the Constand Volume Gas thermometer? On which law does that one work?

Comment: That's what I wrote. Gay-Lussac's law.